# Is it possible to have 2 languages with different syntax but the same semantics?

Tags: syntax, semantics

I have two questions

1. Is it possible to have 2 languages with different syntax but the same semantics?  If not why not else give an example of 2 languages .
2. Is it possible to have 2 languages with same syntax but different semantics?  If not why not else give an example of 2 languages .

I understand that the syntax is the external visible representation of a program and the semantics is the meaning of a program can some one please help answer these questions thank you.

Sorry if I wasn't clear but  I was looking for examples of languages for example for the first question i have C# and VB.NET does that seem appropriate?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer language theory rather than programming.

Comment: @DonRoby I was reading one about quicksort being in-place earlier. That sounds like theory to me too.

Comment: At least quicksort (in-place or not) does involve programming.  But that one might be off-topic as well.

Comment: @DonRoby ok sorry walter white, where would i post theory questions

Comment: @bobthecoder cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DonRoby what is the difference between cs and cstheory?

Comment: Actually, I think cs is still in beta, and I'm not real clear on the difference either - which is why I deleted my comment and upvoted yours.

Answer (score 3):

1) Yeah. Take off the semicolons or require semicolons.

2) Yeah. For the second just do something that makes no sense for all of the statements.

There are lots of Turing machines out there. Technically they all have the same semantics but different syntax.

Comment: The answer is obviously simplistic, but you could take it as far as you want.

Comment: Thanks that helps also can you give me examples of 2 languages for each of the questions so for 1 a language where the syntax is different but same semantics I have C# and VB.NET

Comment: There are no languages that I know of off the top of my head that fit either of your questions. C# and VB.NET have different syntax and different semantics. There may be language A and language-A-with-syntax-that-somebody-thought-was-more-readable floating around somewhere. They will have the same semantics, but I don't know of them off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sure, C{ is exactly like C, except that it uses `{` where C uses `(`, and vice versa. Note that it retains the original meanings of `}` and `)`.
2. Sure, !C is exactly like C, except that `!` means "absolutely!" (there's no operator for "not", so you have to use `~` instead).